# How to find undergraduate earnings data

Tags: data-request, data.gov, collegescorecard

Having difficulty accessing this data file - EARN_MDN_HI_2YR.  have tried the search bar, but have not been successful.

Answer (score 1):

A search for "EARN_MDN_HI_2YR" in Bing leads to the document "[Technical Documentation: College Scorecard Data by Field of Study (PDF)](https://collegescorecard.ed.gov/assets/FieldOfStudyDataDocumentation.pdf)". The field "EARN_MDN_HI_2YR" is a part of the dataset resource "[Most Recent Data by Field of Study](https://data.ed.gov/dataset/college-scorecard-all-data-files-through-6-2020/resources?resource=ff68afc4-6d23-459d-9f60-4006e4f85583)". The download from this page is a zip file containing a CSV file. The CSV file has several columns including the column "EARN_MDN_HI_2YR".

From the Technical Documentation, "The 2020 Scorecard earnings data release makes progress toward the goal of adding measurement points to the earnings data series by publishing median earnings measured two years after completion (EARN_MDN_HI_2YR)."

Answer (score 0):

I do not know where to find a dataset with exactly this column name (on data.gov - noticed your use of the "data.gov" tag only *after* my post was written)

However, in [this dataset](https://github.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/tree/master/data/2018/2018-10-16) on the tidytuesday site (an R learning community), the column is simply called "Median"

```
Median  Median earnings of full-time, year-round workers
```

The original dataset was compiled by Fivethirtyeight in 2012, though.
See data.fivethirtyeight.com and scroll down to   ["The Economic Guide To Picking A College Major"](https://data.fivethirtyeight.com/)     (Sept. 12, 2014)

> All data is from American Community Survey 2010-2012 Public Use Microdata Series.

> Original data and more: http://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/acs/data/pums.html

For details see post on [fivethirtyeight.com](https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/the-economic-guide-to-picking-a-college-major/) about the subject.